# Why is the default value table property dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1 in Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, datastax, datastax-enterprise, datastax-java-driver, datastax-startup

I was going through Cassandra docs and noticed this property. Naturally, I was assuming a read repair would most certainly happen whenever a read request is made to Cassandra. Why is the default value set to 0.1, instead of 1? Also, what would be the consequences of setting it to 1 ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Cassandra performs read repair whenever a read reveals inconsistencies among replicas.

If you want cassandra to perform read repair even after a completely consistent read, you can configure it with `dclocal_read_repair_chance`.

**dclocal_read_repair_chance :**

> The probability that a consistent read of a table triggers a read repair. It is confined to the same datacenter as the coordinator node.

*Cassandra compares and coordinates all replicas, even those that were not accessed in the successful read.*

if you set `dclocal_read_repair_chance` to 1. Then the probability of consistent read will trigger read repair is 1. So every time you perform read request, cassandra will trigger read repair, that is very resource-intensive.

Recommendations: if the table is for time series data, it can be set to 0 (zero). For other tables, the more performant strategy is to set dc_local_read_repair_chance to 0.1

Source : http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/tabProp.html#tabProp__cql_tabprop_more_read_repairs

Comment: I see. I suppose, that for a very write heavy, and seldom but important read queries, setting dclocal_read_repair_chance = 1 might out work nicely. Would have to load test though